# Android , cannot resolve ImageDecoder

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use [ImageDecoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageDecoder) in my Android app and the IDE says it cannot resolve it. Should i add any library for this to be resolved? My compileSdkVersion is 27 , which seems to be the latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> public final class ImageDecoder  extends Object implements
>   AutoCloseable

A class for converting encoded images (like PNG, JPEG, WEBP, GIF, or HEIF) into Drawable or Bitmap objects.

- API Level required **`P or Higher`**.

You should set **`compileSdkVersion 'android-P'`**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 'android-P'

defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion 'P'
}
```

[**`Set Up the Android P SDK`**](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk)